# Label throws error if text boxes are blank

Tags: c#

I have the code below which works fine, but if I leave the text boxes blank it throws an error.  I would like to first check if any are blank then throw an error message in lblSalary.Text.  How could I re-write this?  C#

Thanks

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Double AnnualHours;
        AnnualHours = Convert.ToDouble(txtAnnualHours.Text);
        Double Rate;
        Rate = Convert.ToDouble(txtRate.Text);
        Double Salary;
        Salary = (AnnualHours * Rate);
        lblSalary.Text = "$" + Salary.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this a homework question? If so, you should add the "homework" tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `convert.ToDouble` use [`double.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.tryparse.aspx) and handle the case where it returns false.

```
double AnnualHours;
if (!double.TryParse(txtAnnualHours.Text, out AnnualHours))
{
    // Set label text here, as we couldn't convert to a double
}
else
{
    // AnnualHours contains the double value.
}
```

---

**NOTE:** Because you're dealing with money, you should use the [decimal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) type, not the double type. Decimal can correctly represent base 10 numbers (123, 157.2, 0.5) exactly, whereas double cannot.

See here: [decimal vs double! - Which one should I use and when?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1165761/decimal-vs-double-which-one-should-i-use-and-when)

Answer (score 1):

Use [Double.TryParse()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/994c0zb1.aspx) to parse string in safe manner

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    double annualHours = 0;
    double.TryParse(txtAnnualHours.Text, out annualHours);
    double rate = 0;
    double.TryParse(txtRate.Text, out rate);
    double salary = (annualHours * rate);
    lblSalary.Text = "$" + salary.ToString();
}
```

If you need to do some conditional calculations depends on whether value was provided or not (user entered a valid number in textbox):

```
bool isAnnualHoursValid = double.TryParse(txtAnnualHours.Text, out annualHours);
if (isAnnualHoursValid)
{
     // ask user to enter valid value or use some default
}
```